# Fuzziness does not works with query string in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I've got some query

```
{ type: 'Wandering',
   zone: '1',
   personName: 'Dmytro',
   personRoom: 'Room_73' } }
```

And use wildcard and fuzziness with a query string, but looks like, when I type 'Wandring' or 'wadnering' , I expected fuzziness makes transpositions.

```
 'query': {
                    'query_string' : {
                        'query': `*${search}*~1 OR *${search}~1`,
                        'analyze_wildcard': true,
                    },
                }
```

,

Define mapping. maybe it depends how document indexes.
**mapping**

```
{
  "call": {
    "mappings": {
      "Call": {
        "properties": {
          "personName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "personRoom": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "zone": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the complete mapping of your index?

Comment: @AndreiStefan added mapping

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
                'query_string' : {
                    'query': `${search}~1`,
                    'analyze_wildcard': true,
                }
```

And regarding wildcards, I suggest having a look at [alternative search types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/partial-matching.html) before looking at this. They are particularly heavy and will perform bad at searches, especially the leading wildcards.